# routing mismatch with rest api in rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my tiny application build with rails 4. i need a api. for that i did the following

i have model named rest_api.rb

```
class RestApi < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

in controller, i created setup controller in controllers/api/rest_apis_controller.rb

```
class Api::RestApisController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authenticate_user!  

def index
@tokens = RestApi.all
respond_to do |format|
    fromat.html
    format.json { render json: @tokens }
    format.xml { render xml: @tokens }
  end
 end

end
```

and finally in my routes.rb file, i did the following

```
namespace :api do get 'tokens', to: "rest_apis#index"

end
```

Now, when i go browse via http:localhost:3000/api/tokens  its showing the following error,

```
No route matches [GET] "/api/tokens"
```

Please suggest me, what to do now ??

my rake routes are,

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#new
    user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)         devise/sessions#destroy
            root GET    /                                 opengrok_pages#index
            help GET    /help(.:format)                   opengrok_pages#help
          report GET    /report(.:format)                 opengrok_pages#load
   api_rest_apis GET    /api/rest_apis(.:format)          api/rest_apis#index
                 POST   /api/rest_apis(.:format)          api/rest_apis#create
new_api_rest_api GET    /api/rest_apis/new(.:format)      api/rest_apis#new
edit_api_rest_api GET    /api/rest_apis/:id/edit(.:format) api/rest_apis#edit
    api_rest_api GET    /api/rest_apis/:id(.:format)      api/rest_apis#show
                 PATCH  /api/rest_apis/:id(.:format)      api/rest_apis#update
                 PUT    /api/rest_apis/:id(.:format)      api/rest_apis#update
                 DELETE /api/rest_apis/:id(.:format)      api/rest_apis#destroy
```

Comment: please show output of `rake routes`

Comment: the route you've specified in routes.rb will match /api/rest_apis

Comment: this does not contain any routes for "/api/tokens" . Try to access "/api/rest_apis"

Comment: i have updated questions with **rake routes**

Comment: but /api/rest_apis showing error `ActionController::UnknownFormat in Api::RestApisController#index` and pointing to this line `respond_to do |format|`

Comment: @NitinJ , @Slicedpan how to make routes for `api/tokens`

Comment: namespace :api do get 'tokens', to: "rest_apis#index" end only if you want to map this for index action.

Comment: @NitinJ thank you, can u say me why its showing `ActionController::UnknownFormat in Api::RestApisController#index`

Comment: @Slicedpan I have updated routes.rb and controller file plz check. Now its showing `template missing` with the following error `Missing template api/rest_apis/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/sbrc/opengrok/app/views" * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@opengrok/gems/devise-3.2.2/app/views" `

Comment: you need to specify the content type, either in the request headers, or by appending the type to the url, '/api/tokens.json'

Comment: @Slicedpan thank you sir. i knew it but u know sometimes shit happens. thaks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the match method

```
match 'api/tokens', to: 'rest_apis#index', via: :get
```